# Matlab - using imquantize()

Tags: matlab

I found that there is a method called `imquantize` in order to make a quantization of the input image. I'm trying to make a quantization using **4-bits**. I did the following:

```
>> quan = imquantize(im,16);
```

But, I got the following error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'imquantize' for input arguments of type 'unit8'
```

How can I go around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`imquantize` is a new function introduced in [Image Processing Toolbox R2012b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html). You can check which image processing toolbox is installed on your matlab (if any) by invoking this command:

```
ver
```

Answer (score 2):

`imquantize` is [new to](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/whatsnew.html) the 2012b release of the Image Processing Toolbox. Therefore, if you don't have 2012b (released last month), you won't have `imquantize`.

In any case, your usage of `imquantize` would be incorrect. `imquantize` takes, as a second argument, a vector of levels to be used as the threshold. Those levels could, for example, be obtained through `multithresh` (which is also new to IPT 2012b).